# How to select only the first rows for each unique value of a column with sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

Let's say I have this table

```
name | year | month | val 
-----+------+-------+------
user1| 2019 | 02    | YES
user1| 2019 | 01    | NO
user2| 2019 | 02    | YES
user3| 2019 | 02    | NO
```

I want to get the last answer for each user( MAX(year) and MAX(month) )

```
name | val 
-----+-----
user1| YES
user2| YES
user3| NO
```

my actual sql request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, val 
FROM answer AS sf 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON u.id_user = sf.id_user 
WHERE sf.id_feedback = 1  
ORDER BY name
```

I'm working with Microsoft Access

Comment: Are the `year` & `month` fields numerical? Is this data really stored in a single table? As your sample query would indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

First group to get the max dates of each user and then join:

```
select a.name, a.val 
from answer as a inner join (
  select name, max(dateserial(year, month, 1)) as maxdate
  from answer
  group by name
) as g on g.name = a.name and g.maxdate = dateserial(a.year, a.month, 1)
```

If the `year` and `month` columns are Text then:

```
select a.name, a.val 
from answer as a inner join (
  select name, max(year & month) as maxdate
  from answer
  group by name
) as g on g.name = a.name and g.maxdate = (a.year & a.month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery :

```
select t.name, t.val
from table t 
where t.pk = (select top 1 t1.pk
              from table t1
              where t1.name = t.name
              order by t1.year desc, t1.month desc
             );
```

`pk` indicate identity column that identify column ordering.

Comment: you assume a pk column exists here.  There is nothing in the question about pk.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method, using a correlated subquery:

```
select a.name, a.val from answer a
where not exists 
(select 1 from answer b where a.name = b.name and a.year < b.year and a.month < b.month)
```

**EDIT:** Corrected code below to account for cases in which the year fields match, but month fields differ: (thanks @Scorpioo590)

```
select a.name, a.val from answer a
where not exists 
(select 1 from answer b where a.name = b.name and (a.year < b.year or (a.year = b.year and a.month < b.month)))
```

Alternatively, using `dateserial`:

```
select a.name, a.val from answer a
where not exists 
(select 1 from answer b where a.name = b.name and dateserial(a.year,a.month,1) < dateserial(b.year,b.month,1))
```

Comment: This would only work if both year and month of the desired entry are bigger than all other values. Assume you have two rows 2019-01 and 2019-02. Since there does not exist an entry where the year is bigger, both entries would be picked

Comment: `WHERE a.name = b.name AND (a.year < b.year OR (a.year = b.year AND a.month < b.month))` should do the job.

Comment: @Scorpioo590 Many thanks, I had overlooked this case - I have updated my answer above. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.